# github actions - use property from pom.xml?

Tags: java, github, pom.xml, github-actions

I run tests on GitHub Actions, like this:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Runs Elasticsearch
        uses: elastic/elastic-github-actions/elasticsearch@master
        with:
          stack-version: 7.16.1

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 17

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

The version of ElasticSearch is currently fixed; but in my project I include the ElasticSearch client 7.16.3. I would like to use that version in the `stack-version` as well. Is there a preferred way to extract a property from the `pom.xml` and use that in the Action?

Comment: You would probably have to use a script first (or command lines), to extract the version from the pom.xml and save into a env variable to use it with the elasticsearch action.

Comment: Ah. That make sense. I was hoping there was an easier way, but this will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get-xml-info](https://github.com/mavrosxristoforos/get-xml-info) to read a property from the pom.xml

```yaml
      - name: Get elasticsearch version from pom.xml
        id: get-elasticsearch-version
        uses: mavrosxristoforos/get-xml-info@1.0
        with:
          xml-file: 'pom.xml'
          xpath: '//*[local-name()="elasticsearch.version.property.tagname"]'

      - name: Runs Elasticsearch
        uses: elastic/elastic-github-actions/elasticsearch@master
        with:
          stack-version: ${{ steps.get-elasticsearch-version.outputs.info }}
```